# Problem running NPM run dev on new Laravel Installation

Tags: laravel, npm, node-modules

I am getting the following error when trying to run npm run dev on a new Laravel 8 installation.

```
> cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js

/[REDACTED]/public_html/node_modules/cross-env/src/index.js:23
    )
    ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
    at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:549:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:586:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:494:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:453:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:445:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:504:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/[redacted]/public_html/node_modules/cross-env/src/bin/cross-env.js:3:18)
```

```
npm ERR! node v6.17.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
```

My package.json is as follows

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --disable-host-check --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.19",
        "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
        "cross-env": "^7.0",
        "jquery": "^3.2",
        "laravel-mix": "^5.0.1",
        "lodash": "^4.17.19",
        "popper.js": "^1.12",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^2.3.1",
        "sass": "^1.20.1",
        "sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
        "vue": "^2.5.17",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10"
    }
}
```

Been trying for hours, even launched a new server with a fresh install but same error. I have tried the following.

```
rm -rf node_modules
rm package-lock.json yarn.lock
npm cache clear --force
npm install
```

Comment: Use npm run Prod

Comment: It's the same error

Comment: Your versions of npm/node seem to be outdated, have you tried updating?

Comment: Do any of your existing files have a `)` that is not supposed to there? As it says `Unexpected token )` it's finding it somewhere it shouldn't be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was fixed after updating nmp/node